# Flutter Global Keyboard Shortcuts

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I am writing an application that should support searching some content. For this I implemented a search `TextField`. Now I would like to focus said `TextField` when the key combination `ctrl` + `F` is pressed.

In order to implement this, I wrapped my view in both a `Shortcuts` and `Actions` component as follows:

```dart
return Scaffold(
  body: Shortcuts(
    shortcuts: {
      LogicalKeySet(LogicalKeyboardKey.keyF, LogicalKeyboardKey.control): MTCSearchIntent(),
    },
    child: Actions(
      actions: {
        MTCSearchIntent: MTCFocusAction(null),
      },
      child: ...
    ),
  ),
);
```

This implementation works if the search bar is already focused, but that kind of defeats the purpose of focusing it.. So I was wondering, how can I apply the `Shortcut` listener to the entire screen? Or asked differently, what determines the scope of the interactions, the `Shortcut` component, the `Action` component, something related to the `FocusNode`?

The example on [flutter.dev](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Shortcuts-class.html) don't seem to work globally either. In fact they don't seem to work at all for me.

I reproduced the example using a minimal example here: https://dartpad.dev/?id=55902a179be137d9025ea02170d749a7

When the TextField is focused, the `ArrowUp`and `ArrowDown` actions work as intended. However, if any other part of the application is highlighted, the `Intent` is never triggered.